# How can I share data between my iOS app and third-party apps?

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I would like to share some strings from my app to other apps.
For example:
A third-party app implements my library and my library gets some strings from my ios app.
Can I use App Extensions for this? Or what is the best practice for this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the File Provider App Extension?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider

Comment: I don't want to show any UI. For example, the third-party app is starting, call my library, my library gets a string from my application without any user interaction and shows this string value in the third-party app.